# How to pass array of data from view to controller laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel php. I need to pass an array of data from view to controller to further use for query. what will be the best way? i am passing data from url, but i am not able to pass an array from url. do i need to use javascript for that ? or just laravel is enough thanks

```
@foreach($nam as $ergebnisse)
    <input type="hidden" id="texture" name="texture[]" value="{{$ergebnisse->texture}}"/>
@endforeach
```

i am saving the whole array in the hidden field . how can i pass this array to the controller? thanks

Controller Method

```
 public function getErgebnisse($geometrie,$name){


    $nam=Ergebnisse::where('name_id', $name)
     ->where('geometrie_id', $geometrie)->orderBy( DB::raw('(aussehen) + (farbe)+(deformation)+(geruch)+(texture)'))->get();


    return view('pages.ergebnisse')->with('nam',$nam);        

}
```

Route

```
Route::get('ergebnisse/{geometrie}/{name}',[
        'as' => 'get_ergebnisse',
        'uses' => 'ForumController@getErgebnisse'
        ]);
```

I need to pass it thorugh the link something like this.but array

```
@foreach($mix as $mix)

<li><a href="{{ URL::route('get_list',['id' =>$mix->name->id,$mix->geometrie->id,$mix->probe,$mix->temperatur,$mix->zeit])}}">{{$mix->name->name}}:{{$mix->geometrie->name}}:{{$mix->probe}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show us your form declaration and controller method that is intercepting the submit request?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i edited the question.actually i dont need to pass it always through the form submission. i need to pass it thorugh url param as i am already working with the url param with other pages.